# Is the use of StringTemplate with a styled string documented behavior?

Tags: string-manipulation, documentation, style, templates

I was pleasantly surprised to find out that [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) appears to work with styled (formatted) strings, with the style of the slots applied to the inserted expressions:

[image]

(The string was formatted using the **Format** menu.)

Is this usage intended or documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this follows from the representation of styles ([and other boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html)) in strings.

For example,  this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

is really represented like this in a string:

```
template="a \!\(\*\nStyleBox[\"``\",\nFontColor->RGBColor[1,0,0]]\) and a ``"
```

Then either with `StringForm` or `StringTemplate` we get

[image]

```
In[10]:= StringTemplate[template]["foo", "bar"]

Out[10]= "a \!\(\*StyleBox[\"foo\",\nFontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]\) and a bar"
```

It's just plain substitution.

---

**EDIT:**  This view also gives ideas on how to break substitution:

[image]

It appears that there is no special support for styling, it's all a side effect of how style boxes are encoded in strings.

Comment: Do you get the same error that I reported?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If I try to convert it by typing into it then yes, I get the error.  Furthermore, the string is corrupted.  If I convert it by changing the cell style then everything is fine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Further testing shows that the error is not related to `StringTemplate`.  Just make a styled string, evaluate it, and try typing in the output cell.  The cell contents will be corrupted and the error appears.

Comment: Thank you.  I should have explored that further before posting.