# How to create a multicolored string?

Tags: string-manipulation, color

I'm interested in displaying a string composed from sub-strings of different colors.
Mathematica allows one to create a list comprising sub-strings of different colors, for example

```
{Style["Blue", Blue], Style["Red", Red]}
```

I would like to create a string looking like

[image]

StringJoin doesn't enable to tackle the problem

Comment: Do you need a `String` or do you need to make the output look like what you show? If the latter, use `Row` on the list.

Comment: It is enough to make an desired output.

Comment: Many related questions: [(7008)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7008/121), [(7732)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7732/121), [(10990)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/121), [(29817)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29817/121), [(45132)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45132/121), [(73822)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73822/121), [(100371)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100371/121)

Answer (score 4):

For display purposes you can use `Row` (as suggested by Szabolcs in comments).

Alternatively, you can use [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html) or [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) after wrapping styled strings with `ToString[#, StandardForm]`:

```
StringRiffle[ ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ {Style["Red", Red, 24], 
    Style["Blue", Blue, 16]},""]
```

[image]

`````
StringTemplate["````"] @@
 (ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ {Style["Red", Red, 24], Style["Blue", Blue, 16]})
`````

[image]

To get a string object you can use

```
str = StringJoin[
  ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ {Style["Red", Red, 24], Style["Blue", Blue, 16]}]
```

[image]

```
Head[str]
```

> String